# Is kissing children recommended?

Tags: hadith, kissing

As far as I know, psychologists emphasize kissing children and likewise believe that is has a very positive effect on kids. I wonder what the viewpoint of Islam is regarding this issue? Is there any hadith concerning this matter?

Answer (score 3):

- It is **permissible** (جائز) out of **mercy and compassion**.
- It is **forbidden** (حرام) out of **lust**.

Hadith 225, Riyad As-salihin:

> وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال‏:‏ قبل النبي الحسن بن علي رضي الله عنهما، وعنده الأقرع بن حابس، فقال الأقرع‏:‏ إن لي عشرة من الولد ما قبلت منهم أحدًا‏.‏ فنظر إليه رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال‏:‏ “من لا يرحم لا يرحم” ‏(‏‏(‏متفق عليه‏)‏‏)‏ ‏.
>
> The Prophet (صلى الله عليه و سلم) kissed his grandson Al-Hasan bin 'Ali (May Allah bepleased with them) in the presence of Al-Aqra' bin Habis. Thereupon he remarked: "I have ten children and I have never kissed any one of them." Messenger of Allah (صلى الله عليه و سلم) looked at him and said, "He who does not show mercy to others will not be shown mercy".

Comment: [In regards to salutations in posts.](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/107)